# How to detect if textarea content has changed with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea name="" id="a" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <textarea name="" id="b" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <textarea name="" id="c" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

js

```
const first = document.getElementById("a");
const second = document.getElementById("b");
const third = document.getElementById("c");

first.addEventListener("input", () => {
  second.value = first.value;
});

second.addEventListener("change", () => {
  console.log("work!!")
  third.value = second.value;
});
```

codepen -> https://codepen.io/dmgpgdmgpg/pen/NWRxVbg?editors=1111

first -> second is okay
but second -> third is not work

because The change event is fired for input, select, and textarea elements when a change to the element's value is committed ***by the user.*** (MDN)

how can detect change of second textarea after change of first textarea?

i want pass first to second, second to third (not first -> third)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the third textarea input after each input from the second one, the same way the first one works, try this:

```
<textarea name="" id="a" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<textarea name="" id="b" cols="30" rows="10" oninput="changeText()"></textarea>
<textarea name="" id="c" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

oninput event:

This event is similar to the onchange event. The difference is that the oninput event occurs immediately after the value of an element has changed, while onchange occurs when the element loses focus, after the content has been changed. The other difference is that the onchange event also works on  elements. [source](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp)

**edit:**

if the you need to detect a change that JS triggered and not the user, might be the best way to just add event dispatch

```
const first = document.getElementById("a");
const second = document.getElementById("b");
const third = document.getElementById("c");
const event = new Event('input', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
});

first.addEventListener("input", () => {
  second.value = first.value;
  second.dispatchEvent(event);
});


second.addEventListener ('input', () => {
  third.value = second.value;
});
```

I did not find any way to fire an event from textarea on change that was not from the user himself except triggering it manually

Comment: not work..... becuase input event is by 'user'. but 'second.value = first.value' is not by user....

if i typing text on second textarea, it will work... but 
that's not what I want to do

Comment: So I misunderstood the question, wouldn't it be easier to just change second and third the same way? or you specifically want to change the third textarea on any change on the second one?

Comment: sorry to late. I want 'monitor' if second textarea value is change. The change includes both changes by users and changes by JS.

Comment: I am making a multi-translator project. The first textarea detects input (language A) and requests the text from the api to receive the translated text (language B).

Comment: Put the translated text into the second textarea and the second textarea should detect it.

Comment: When the second textarea detects, it again requests the text to the api, receives the retranslated text (language C) and puts it in the third textarea.
For example English -> French -> Russian

Comment: sorry to late. your solution is good!! I first learned about dispatchEvent.. thank you!!